# How to embed an icon (.ico) in a static library (Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, resources

Is there a way to embed resources (such as icons, dialogs) in a c++ (Win32 API) static library?
My purpose is to embed an icon in the static library in a way that functions that use LoadIcon will work as if it was a normal .exe so the main application can only link to the static library and include a header file, with no requirement to add other files such as .rc files, or .ico files, etc. 
Clearly the main application who uses the static library doesn't have this resource so LoadIcon will fail, however I was wondering if there is a workaround to make it work. A static array with the icon data can work as long as the standard API calls (such as LoadIcon) will work.

To explain further, the person who will be using the static library will only have 2 files: .lib and .h and will not have any .rc file.

Comment: @Michale: Have you tried it? I think it should work.

Comment: Tried what? you didn't include any link

Comment: and you haven't included a [mcve] of your code

Comment: I don't think I have to because its a general question

Comment: if you want more than a general answer such as "yes", you might want to read [ask] then

Comment: It is not possible, you can stop looking.  Consider a DLL project instead.

Comment: Everything is possible. @ChrisTurner there is nothing wrong with this question and there is no need or place for any source code to accompany the question because it describes the problem very well. An appropriate answer would NOT be yes / no but would be a detailed solution, such as: place the icon's data in a static array. Do such and such and pass the following parameter to LoadIcon.

Comment: One direction I was trying to check is:

1. Converting the icon into a static char[] array.
2. Calling   m_hIcon = reinterpret_cast<HICON>(icon_chars);

Here is some of the code that follows. Nothing fails however the icon isn't displayed.

if (m_hIcon) {
  int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
  int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
...

Answer (score 1):

I am posting an answer because after some research I found a way. Using my method, an icon can be used as an integral part of a static library and such library can be used by any type of application).
See also: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1275122/How-to-embed-resources-in-a-Static-Library

1. Icon is converted to a static array of BYTE. [bin2c](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bin2c/) can be used for that.
2. Data is converted into a HICON handle. Here is how I have done that:

   ```
   HICON GetIcon()
   { 
      DWORD dwTmp;
      int offset;
      HANDLE hFile;
      HICON hIcon = NULL;
      offset = LookupIconIdFromDirectoryEx(s_byIconData, TRUE, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
      if (offset != 0)
      {
         hIcon = CreateIconFromResourceEx(s_byIconData + offset, 0, TRUE, 0x00030000, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR | LR_DEFAULTSIZE);
      }
      return hIcon;  
   }
   ```
3. GetIcon is used instead of LoadIcon. 
   Instead of calling:

`m_hIcon = ::LoadIcon(hInstanceIcon, MAKEINTRESOURCE(pXMB->nIcon));`

I call

```
m_hIcon = GetIcon()
```

Comment: Wrong analysis: A console application is a PE image just like a GUI application. Any PE image can store arbitrary sections, including a resource section, and the majority of console applications *do* contain a resource section (that's where version information is stored, for example). The real reason, why you cannot compile resources into static libraries is, because the toolchain doesn't support it.

Comment: This is not an analysis! This is an answer that actually works, since it is based on real code wrote by real programmers. The problem is a real one that caused the issues that has been described in my question. Then, after our team managed to find a solution and make sure it works, I published the answer. Before placing such comments, please take the time and actually test the code. Embedding an icon in a static library is sticky and some people said its impossible. I managed to solve it and published all the steps taken for the benefit of this community.

Comment: I was commenting on the first paragraph, where you conclude that embedding a resource in a static library were not possible, because that library could be linked into a console application, and console applications (presumably) cannot have resources. This is wrong. Console applications are in no way special, other than the subsystem header entries. They can (and commonly do) contain resources. That is not the reason, why you cannot embed resources in static libraries.

Comment: OK. You are right about that. I amended my answer. Console applications can have resources. However, as you rightly say, this isn't the reason why its (almost) impossible to embed resources in static libraries and I published this answer after finding a way...